# StackExchange Id log-in problem using Google mail account

Tags: bug, login, stack-exchange, openid

I have an identity on Stack Overflow.   (n.b. I'd log this as a StackExchange issue - but I cannot get logged in there)

I am registered as also being a member of other communities, e.g. Server Fault, Stack Overflow Meta, English Language Learning, etc.

I'm also informed I have a Stack Exchange identity.

I am failing to log in to it, despite easily logging in to my StackOverflow id.

I am offered 5 OpenId options -

> Stack Exchange, Google, Facebook, Yahoo` and OpenId

and

> Or, you can manually enter your OpenID.

My StackOverflow id was either set up as my Google id, based on my email, or as a StackOverflow id, again based on my Google email id.

Attempting to log in to StackExchange via Google fails with the message

> This login is new to Stack Exchange:
>   stackauth.com/synthetic-open-id/google/[redacted]
>   Confirm and Create New Account Cancel
>   If you think you already have a Stack Exchange account, and you were just trying to associate a new OpenID with your existing account, you're in the wrong place.

So I attempted using the Stack Exchange option

> Sign in with your account
>   Email Password Sign In

This failed, so I used the link for

> If you’ve forgotten or lost your login information
>   click here to recover your account

which leads to

> Account Recovery
>   Forgotten your account's password? Enter your email address and we'll send you a recovery link.

Doing so returns:

> No account with that email was found

(This is a gmail.com email account, that Google sometimes used to alias behind the scenes as a googlemail.com account.  So I also tried with that alias. This also returned

> No account with that email was found

).

Next, I tried

> you can manually enter your OpenID

which returned:

> Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
>   No OpenID endpoint found.

(same goes for the @googlemail.com alias)

Update:

In my Profile's My Logins tab, it lists two login ids

The first is 'Google', the second is '[myRedactedEmailAddress]@gmail.com

I attempted to remove the second, the non-Google one, (but which still uses the same email address), and was informed

> You cannot remove your only login

Comment: Please don't use `code formatting` for things that aren't code.

Comment: Which formatting option is preferred for system responses, if not fixed pitch?

Comment: Maybe quoting rather than coding formatting?

Comment: According to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help fixed pitch is for both Code **AND** for Pre-formatted text.

Comment: @JonH -- Is this guy permanently locked-out? His profile says he hasn't been seen for more than 3 years.

Comment: No idea accounts stay alive unless someone requests it. It could be he just doesn’t come on, is dead, or any plethora of other reasons

Answer (score 1):

**n.b. The following answer worked once.  It is back to not logging in.**

In my Stack Overflow profile, the private information listed the @googlemail.com email address as my email address.

Amending this to @gmail.com then clicking on the `Network Profile` link took me to the Network Profile page, already logged in, instead of taking me to the log-in page as before

I had recently (within the past fortnight) accepted Google's request to stop aliasing my address as @googlemail.com

Comment: This only worked partially.  I have not yet resolved the difference between where this method has been successful, and where it still fails.